# Extract data from one file corresponding to lines from another file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a data file file1 as follows:

```
sample1
some text
sample1

sample2
some text
sample2

sample3
some text
sample3
...
```

And a reference id list in a file2:

```
sample3
sample13
sample21
...
```

I want now to extract the information from file1 corresponding to the lines from file2, so the output would be:

```
sample3
some text
sample3

sample13
some text
sample13

...
```

I tried to use awk and sed, but unfortunately I was not able to print all the lines I need.

Comment: Post the efforts that you made to the question.

Comment: Are `sample` in file1 (last line) and `sample 3`in output  (3rd line) 
 a typo?

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you, I didn't notice, changed it.

Comment: I did `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a)' file2 file1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close but needed to set `RS=""` for the `file1` (to read empty line separated blocks instead of lines):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' file2 RS="" file1
sample3
some text
sample3
```

To separate records you might want to:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n\n"}NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' file2 RS="" file1
sample3
some text
sample3

samplen
...
```

Comment: Yes James, that's one I always have to look up -- well done.